# PostGIS order intersections of line and polygon

Tags: postgis, postgresql, st-intersects, st-split

I have a polygon and a line that goes through it. That line might exit my polygon and enter it again at a later point.

So now I'd like to have a relative position inside my line, where those segments are.

As an example. I have the following polygon and a line.
My result should be TWO segments, where segment one is located at about 0.1 - 0.4% of my line and segment two is located at about 0.6 - 0.9% of my line.

How can I do that using postgis?

What I've tried so far:
`ST_Intersections` -> I do get the segments, but not the indexes.
`ST_LineLocatePoint` -> I would get the index of a point (e.g. the start and end-points of my segments)

Problem with that is that if my line crosses itself, I get wrong results, as those start/end points would exist at least twice.

[image]

So what I can imagine would be nice is a function (I haven't found it and don't know if it exists) that would give me indexes of relative positions of matches as well. Am I just blind? Does such a function exist?

**EDIT:**
So this here is a sample of a polygon I want to cut with a line. It gives me all parts of my line. Inside and outside, which would help me in my further analysis. But the order of `ST_Split` in this case is just not correct. All sub-segments I get from it are in correct order, expect the last two in that example. With other examples the order is reversed. But I NEED to know the proper order to tell where in my original line that intersection happened.

```
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            14.965792894363402,
            47.526699241115935
          ],
          [
            14.970245361328125,
            47.52540968472776
          ],
          [
            14.967606067657472,
            47.52504019924539
          ],
          [
            14.968990087509153,
            47.52488081254758
          ],
          [
            14.966779947280882,
            47.52460550711063
          ],
          [
            14.972037076950071,
            47.52419254624608
          ],
          [
            14.97059941291809,
            47.523286918933046
          ],
          [
            14.973410367965698,
            47.52304783071382
          ]
        ]
      }'), st_geomfromgeojson('{
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              14.96858239173889,
              47.52632976471708
            ],
            [
              14.965996742248535,
              47.52501121988183
            ],
            [
              14.96784210205078,
              47.52302609536715
            ],
            [
              14.971328973770142,
              47.52361294656684
            ],
            [
              14.96858239173889,
              47.52632976471708
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }')));
```

Comment: `ST_Intersection` will return a collection (a `MultiLineString` in the natural case of multi-overlay between areal and lineal features), and the underlying engine should keep order when creating the intersecting segments: `ST_DumpPoints` on that returned geometry returns a `geometry_dump`, having a `path` field of type `NUMERIC[]`, where `path[1]` is the geometry sequence number within the collection, and `path[2]` the vertex sequence number of the given member. The same goes for `ST_Dump`, having only `path[1]` - with these, you should be able to identify the resulting segments.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I don't really understand it yet though. So I see that `ST_DumpPoints` gives me all the points each and that `ST_Dump` will give me the whole sequences as linestrings.
My main problem: So if my input is a number of points or a linestring (the results of the dump, so basically a sub-line of my original line) how can I get the relative start/end inside the originating line?
So how can I say, given that input line, and this sub-line-string -> where inside that input line is that sub-line-string? Which are the relative start/end positions?

Comment: @geozelot I updated my question with a concrete sample of `ST_Split` (but i've seen the same for `ST_Intersection`) where the order of the result is just not correct. But without that proper order, I can't find the exact places where inside my original line, my intersection lies. Would be very very glad for any further advice!

Answer (score 3):

Run

```
SELECT ln.id,
       its.path[1] AS seq,
       ROUND(start_frac::NUMERIC, 3) AS start_frac,
       ROUND(end_frac::NUMERIC, 3) AS end_frac,
       its.geom
FROM   <polygons> AS ply
JOIN   <lines> AS ln
  ON   ST_Intersects(ply.geom, ln.geom)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
       ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(ply.geom, ln.geom)) AS its
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
       ST_LineLocatePoint(ln.geom, ST_StartPoint(its.geom)) AS start_frac
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
       ST_LineLocatePoint(ln.geom, ST_EndPoint(its.geom)) AS end_frac
;
```

Here

- we first calculate the `ST_Intersection`, and `ST_Dump` its result
- we then find the fraction of line length at which both `ST_StartPoint` and `ST_EndPoint` of each dumped segment project on its parent line

I use `[CROSS JOIN] LATERAL` here since it let's us elegantly expand *sets* of rows returned by their statements.

The `seq` holds a sequence (`INT` starting at 1) referencing the relative segment position to their parent line - you can uniquely identify segments by `ln.id` & `seq`.

---

[image]
*Tick-marks correspond to 1%, 5% and 10% steps of line length*.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your detailed help! This seems very promising!!!
May I ask one more question. If my input line crosses itself (my input is a gps track and that quite often intersects itself), the results don't seem to be correct any more. I get a number of segments where e.g. end-fraction is way past start-fraction. Some where there are segments where start-section and end-section cover most of the line (which it does not) and then mans sections in-between.
Would be super happy if you have an idea for that as well! Thanks a lot!!!!